# How to show dynamic values in Laravel HTML 5.1 form?

Tags: forms, laravel-5.1

I am trying to edit form data in Laravel, but don't know how to show data dynamically in a input field of a Laravel form.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
{!! Form::text('fname','<?php echo Auth::user()->fname ?>', array('id'=>'fname', 'class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'text')) !!}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of this?

Comment: it prints the whole html as it is

Comment: Can you try `{{ Auth::user()->fname }}` instead of the `<?php` tag?

Comment: oh yes! it works..., thanks so much :)

Comment: Actually, it should work without the curly braces too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping it in `<?php` tag, you can just pass along the data into the function, like so:

```
{!! Form::text('fname', Auth::user()->fname, array('id'=>'fname', 'class'=>'form-control', 'type'=>'text')) !!}
```